# How to compare 2 files in python, ignoring whitespace

Tags: python

How can I compare two files to check if they have the same contents, ignoring whitespace, in Python?

This is something I need to do programmatically. I have a pytest test and while it passes locally on my windows computer it fails in our linux build environment and I believe whitespace is to blame.

I tried using filecmp, however that doesn't give me the option to ignore whitespace.

Comment: do you have any examples?

Comment: also code usage?

Comment: Do you just want a diff in your editor or "some" tool or do you seek to do diffing explicitly via python? Is enough to strip out whitespace and compare hashes?

Comment: Take a look at [`difflib.ndiff`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) It has an option that can be used to filter out whitespace.

Comment: How big are the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are small, I think the easiest way would be to read them into strings, remove whitespace, and then compare:

```
def same_excluding_whitespace(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, "r") as f1:
        content1 = "".join(f1.read().split())

    with open(file2, "r") as f2:
        content2 = "".join(f2.read().split())

    return content1 == content2
```

If the files are large, you can compare them 1 character at a time and avoid loading anything large into memory:

```
def same_excluding_whitespace2(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2:
        while True:
            char1 = f1.read(1)
            while char1.isspace():
                char1 = f1.read(1)

            char2 = f2.read(1)
            while char2.isspace():
                char2 = f2.read(1)

            if not char1 and not char2:
                return True

            if char1 != char2:
                return False
```